# fluent validation validator ignoring custom rules created in domain layer

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, fluent, fluentvalidation, llblgen

i have a generated domain model using LLBLGEN, and im validating those validation rules which are created at domain layer using the fluentvalidation.TestHelper features.

an example of my validation looks like this:

```
public partial class MyClassValidator : AbstractValidator< MyClass >
```

{

```
public MyClassValidator()
{
RuleFor(x => x.MyObjMoneyValue)
.NotEmpty() 
.WithName("MyObjMoneyValue")
.WithState(x => NewFluentCustomState(x)); 

CustomRules();
} 
}
```

so i have a custom set of rules which arent generated by LLBLGEN which is a partial class to the generated rules which allows me to write some custom rules that arent based on the database (i.e. not null).

```
public partial class MyClassValidator 
{
    private void CustomRules()
    {
        RuleFor(q => q.MyObjMoneyValue)
            .GreaterThan(0)
            .WithMessage("Value must be greater than 0")
            .WithState(NewFluentCustomState);
```

i have a test to test this case:

```
_validator.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(q => q.MyObjMoneyValue, 0);
```

However, this fails to test the custom rules.. 
any idea how how i can test the custom rules?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Custom(x => x.) for your custom validation no need for another methods